# Django rest_framework relations

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So I am looking at [django rest_framework relatedfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#relatedfield) and I came up with a question on serializing a model with the following architecture:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    foo = models.Foreignkey(Foo, null=True, blank=True)
    bar_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bar = models.Foreignkey(Bar, null=True, blank=True)
    #...
```

I cannot call my `FooSerializer` or `BarSerializer` if they are null. I thought about creating my `FooBarSerializer` with [serializer method fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield) as such:

```
class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField('foo_info')
    bar = serializers.SerializerMethodField('bar_info')

    class Meta:
        model = FooBar

    def foo_info(self, obj):
        if obj.foo_flag:
            return FooSerializer()
        else:
            return False

    def bar_info(self, obj):
        if obj.bar_flag:
            return BarSerializer()
        else:
            return False
```

But I don't really know if there is really a backend difference when it comes to the `SerializerMethodField` and `RelatedField`. **What would be the best practice in this situation?**

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with the flags and fields?  I'm not clear why you're using MethodField's to begin with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        depth = 1
```

It looks like you are after nested serialization, where the serialized FooBar contains serialized representations of the Foo and Bar models. This will, in turn, serialize Foo and Bar with `serializers.ModelSerializer`.

If you need to customize serialization of Foo or Bar, you've done the right thing creating `FooSerializer` and `BarSerializer` classes. Now you need to attach them to FooBarSerializer, so try this:

```
class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(required=False)
    bar = BarSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
```

Further reading:

- `depth` attribute [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-nested-serialization)
- `required=False` with nesting [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#dealing-with-nested-objects)
- Here's the [issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/384) that allowed empty relations with nested serializers and it's been in REST framework since 2.1.14.

Comment: This is great. I need to check it all out, but if it all works, I will accept this. I do have a question...if I want to add information to the `data` that goes into the `Foo/BarSerializer`, how do I do that?

Comment: Some options: you could add [extra fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-fields-explicitly), [extra context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#including-extra-context) or customize field values with `transform_<fieldname>`.